# Understanding Exception Handling on the context of Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

On the context of Inheritance of the Exception handling class

[image]

Exception is inherited from BaseException, so all the implementation of the BaseException class should be found inside the Exception class, from this understanding when i run the code

```
import sys
class calc:

  def learn_exception(self):
    try:
      sys.exit()

    except Exception as exp:
      print(f'system exited {exp}')
    
    print('code running after main execution')

c=calc()
c.learn_exception()
```

The above code should enter into the Exception class, then it should resume the normal code flow, but it is not happening, but when i add this code snippet

```
import sys
class calc:

  def learn_exception(self):
    try:
      sys.exit()

    except Exception as exp:
      print(f'system exited {exp}')

    except BaseException as ex:
      print(f'error while running the code {ex}')
    
    print('code running after main execution')

c=calc()
c.learn_exception()
```

The code is entering inside the BaseException class and it is resuming the normal flow. can somebody help me undertand how it is possible

Comment: `SystemExit` is *not* a subclass of `Exception`, so `except Exception as exp` does *not* catch the exception raised by `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Your first assertion is unfounded. What do you think that `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` are?

Comment: @chepner, my question is when BaseException can handle the system exit then why not Exception class handle the same error, after all it is being derived from the BaseException class, so it should have all the implementation of the BaseException class

Comment: Two "siblings" do not have the same functionality, and `BaseException` *supplies* functionality to its subclasses; it doesn't know anything about `SystemExit` to pass on to `Exception`.

Comment: @chepner, if BaseException doesnot know anything abt SystemExit, then how is the system exit is handled by the BaseException

Comment: Because a `SystemExit` exception is a *kind* of `BaseException`. Anything you can do with a `BaseException` (which is pretty much limited to catching it), you can do with a `SystemExit`. The converse is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemExit is derived from BaseException as is Exception. If you want to "catch" SystemExit you have to do so explicitly **or** catch BaseException

Comment: well, i can very well use SystemExit to catch the SystemExit Exception, but my question is not that, my question is very simple, when BaseException can handle the system exit then why not Exception class handle the same, after all it is being derived from the BaseException class

Comment: @LijinDurairaj SystemExit is not derived from (a subclass of) Exception

Comment: so, the BaseException class should not be have the system exit implementation either, right?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj You may find this useful: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: this documentation: docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html , answered my question

Answer (score 0):

[as per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

> A class in an except clause is compatible with an exception if it is
> the same class or a base class thereof (but not the other way around —
> an except clause listing a derived class is not compatible with a base
> class). For example, the following code will print B, C, D in that
> order:

```
class B(Exception):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

class D(C):
    pass

for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except D:
        print("D")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except B:
        print("B")
```

Note that if the except clauses were reversed (with except B first), it would have printed B, B, B — the first matching except clause is triggered.